# URL Rewrite htaccess from root to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a simple home page (`index.html`) which has a hyperlink to a subfolder named as `main` which contains `index.html`. You can witness the same at: [rajiviyer.in](http://rajiviyer.in)

Code for hyperlink:

```
<p>Go to sub folder page - <a href="Main/">Main</a></p>
```

How to configure `.htaccess` for this so, that I can directly access `http://site_name/main/*.html`?

Comment: Please try to improve your spelling. Although high level English is not expected here, but you can get much better acceptance if you follow this [six simple spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370).

Comment: @peterh *these  // I'm sorry, but I couldn't resist ;)

Comment: @SWdV Resist what?

Comment: @peterh Commenting (because you said _this_ in a comment about spelling)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PHP:

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://www.domain.de/main");
    header("Connection: close");
?>
```

Or, like you actually want it, with a .htaccess entry:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.de/main
```

Comment: Thanks, I created a .htaccess entry with the below: 

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# Set default page for a directory to index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rajiviyer.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rajiviyer.in/$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 / http://www.rajiviyer.in/main

But I am getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I am unable to see the home page. I directly get this error when I access the site.

Comment: Do you only want to redirect from the root to this subfolder. Or from all links to /main? Try the code above. With your code you route in a circle.

Comment: Yes, only from root to this subfolder.

Comment: When I tried with PHP its not working, I get 404 error

Comment: Using  Redirect 301 / rajiviyer.in/main

Will it not redirect all the request coming to the domain

Comment: Did you replace domain.de with yours? header("Location: http://www.rajiviyer.in/main");

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment, please try the below instead:

```all
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

# Set default page for a directory to index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

# Turn on the rewrite engine for this override
RewriteEngine On

# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rajiviyer\.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rajiviyer.in/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect site root to main directory
RewriteRule ^$ /main/ [R=302,L]
```

Once you're happy, change `302` to `301` to make the redirect cached by browsers and search engines.

Comment: Thanks Mike,  you mean 302 to 302? I will check the code and shall let you know

Comment: I am getting 403 code should I place the htaccess inside main

Comment: Sorry about that - have fixed the typo. No, it should be placed in the root.

Comment: I see that the redirection is working, but it appears the `main` directory is not accessible. Do you have another `.htaccess` in there? I also noticed that `/main/index.html` returns a 404.